# How to fix "Method 'ApplyServices' does not have an implementation" at Program with efCore 3 and .net core 3

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.0, ef-core-3.0

I'm developing a new Web API on EfCore 3 and .net core 3 and not able to start this because of an error "Method 'ApplyServices' in type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Infrastructure.Internal.SqlServerOptionsExtension' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Version=3.0.0.0' does not have an implementation.

I should note that ApplicationContext that I inject to my project is located in another project (.net core 3 too).
Debugging showed that application is crashed in this part of code -->

```
    services
                    .AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options =>
                        options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

Here you can see All StartUp Class

```
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
            {
                _configuration = configuration;
            }

            private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

            public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                services.AddOptions();

                var connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

                services
                    .AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options =>
                        options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

                services.AddControllers()
                    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Latest)
                    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);

                services.AddHostedService<MigratorHostedService>();
            }

            public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
            {
                app.UseCors("AllowAll");

                app.UseStaticFiles();

                app.UseRouting();
            }
```

Here is MigratorHostedService

```
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
            public MigratorHostedService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
            {
                _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
            }

            public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
                {
                    var myDbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationContext>();

                    await myDbContext.Database.MigrateAsync();
                }
            }

            public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) => Task.CompletedTask;
```

Here is Program

```
 private const int Port = ...;

        public static async Task Main()
        {
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

            var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder();

            host.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(ConfigureWebHost);

            await host.Build()
                .RunAsync(cts.Token)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        private static void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.UseUrls($"http://*:{Port}");
            builder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            builder.UseDefaultServiceProvider((context, options) =>
            {
                options.ValidateOnBuild = true;
            });
        }
```

As .net core 3 is new, I haven't found solution of this problem

Also my project packages:

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

      <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
        <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);NU1605</NoWarn>
      </PropertyGroup>

      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="JetBrains.Annotations" Version="2019.1.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0-preview-18579-0056" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0-preview.19080.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.0.0">
          <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
          <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="3.0.0-preview.19080.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="3.0.0-preview.19080.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.6" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.0.0">
          <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
          <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetAppHost" Version="3.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Utils" Version="3.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.2" />
      </ItemGroup>

    </Project>
```

ApplicationContext

```
public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces define the signature of a Functions - name, arguments, return value. But they can not define any code for them. They expect the class that implements them, to give them code. You have to give an implementation.

Now this is a absolutely valid implementation for every imaginable Interface functions:

```
{
  throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

So is this:

```
{
  throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

It even fullfills the "must return a value" rule.

It is also the default implementation. And in some cases it might be the only implementation. Not every function of every Interface might have a sensible implementation for every class that implements it. In some cases, the function being not implemented [is even expected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator.reset?view=netframework-4.8#remarks).

If you control that class, you have to provide an actuall implementation for that function.

If you do not control that class, then you are largely out of luck.

I can not see any call to `ApplyServices`. So that means you hand the instante to to some code that expects the function to exist (and have sensible behavior). Wich is not the case.

Whatever you tried to do that expects a class with code for `ApplyServices`, it can not be applied to this class. There should be a way to hand some code to the function. Like there is a override for Array.Sort() that accepts a custom Comparer, rather then using a default Comparer. But if not, it is simply a no-go.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I found this method at `options.IsConfigured` but it is false so now I have this Exception: "**No database provider has been configured for this DbContext**" Also with this Exception I can show you my ApplicationContext

Answer (score 0):

after all tryings the right implementation of startup was there

```html
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                x => x.MigrationsAssembly("CRM.API")));

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder
                            .AllowAnyOrigin()
                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                            .AllowAnyHeader();
                        //.AllowCredentials();
                    });
            });

            services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
        }
        
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors("AllowAll");

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Departments}/{action=GetDepartments}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

And right Program class implementation was there

```html
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = BuildWebHost(args);

            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
                try
                {
                    var context = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationContext>();

                    await context.Database.MigrateAsync();
                    await DbInitializer.InitializeAsync(context);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                    logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while seeding the database.");
                }
            }

            host.Run();
        }


        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
```

Sure, this answer will help you